# Sen2Like GDALRasterizeOptions Failed to process SRS definition

Tags: python, gdal, sentinel-2, osgeo, gdal-rasterize

While running sen2like tool in single-tile-mode an error related to osgeo gdal occurred (Python):

```
[INFO ] 2021-04-07 13:01:06 - reader - Sentinel2MTL Class
[INFO ] 2021-04-07 13:01:06 - reader - Product: sen2like-master/data/Sentinel2/33TWF/S2A_MSIL1C_20200313T095031_N0209_R079_T33TWF_20200313T102505.SAFE
[INFO ] 2021-04-07 13:01:10 - sentinel2 - SAT_AZ , SAT_ZENITH, SUN_AZ, SUN_ZENITH
[INFO ] 2021-04-07 13:01:10 - sentinel2 - UNIT = DEGREES (scale: x100) :
[INFO ] 2021-04-07 13:01:10 - sentinel2 - /home/ec2-user/wd/14572/S2A_MSIL1C_20200313T095031_N0209_R079_T33TWF_20200313T102505.SAFE/tie_points.tif
[INFO ] 2021-04-07 13:01:10 - sentinel2 - Generating nodata mask from band B01
[INFO ] 2021-04-07 13:01:11 - image_file - Written: /home/ec2-user/wd/14572/S2A_MSIL1C_20200313T095031_N0209_R079_T33TWF_20200313T102505.SAFE/nodata_pixel_mask_B01.tif
[INFO ] 2021-04-07 13:01:11 - sentinel2 - Generating validity mask from cloud mask

Traceback (most recent call last):
File “sen2like-master/sen2like/sen2like/sen2like.py”, line 435, in
sys.exit(main(with_multiprocess_support=True))
File “sen2like-master/sen2like/sen2like/sen2like.py”, line 430, in main
start_process(tile, _products, args, start_date, end_date)
File “sen2like-master/sen2like/sen2like/sen2like.py”, line 253, in start_process
process(_product, args.bands)
File “sen2like-master/sen2like/sen2like/sen2like.py”, line 284, in process
product.mtl.get_valid_pixel_mask(os.path.join(config.get(“wd”), product.name, ‘valid_pixel_mask.tif’))
File “/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/sen2like-master/sen2like/sen2like/core/readers/sentinel2.py”, line 404, in get_valid_pixel_mask
xRes=res, yRes=res)
File “/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/custom-miniconda/miniconda/envs/sen2like_ker/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/gdal.py”, line 1163, in Rasterize
(opts, callback, callback_data) = RasterizeOptions(**kwargs)
File “/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/custom-miniconda/miniconda/envs/sen2like_ker/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/gdal.py”, line 1150, in RasterizeOptions
return (GDALRasterizeOptions(new_options), callback, callback_data)
File “/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/custom-miniconda/miniconda/envs/sen2like_ker/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/gdal.py”, line 3530, in init
this = _gdal.new_GDALRasterizeOptions(*args)
RuntimeError: Failed to process SRS definition: EPSG:32633
```

I don’t understand the error, the installed version of gdal is the 3.0.1 as required.
gdal_rasterize documentation says *“The <srs_def> may be any of the usual GDAL/OGR forms, complete WKT, PROJ.4, EPSG:n”*. So the parameter should accept “EPSG:32633”

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue looks to be due to GDAL Configuration.
Did you activate environment with ""conda activate sen2like_ker"

Please note that for anomaly tracking & timely support, a dedicated space has been created in the ESA STEP forum:
https://forum.step.esa.int/t/sen2like-tool-for-harmonize-sentinel-2-and-landsat-8-imagery/26443